# Skype for Business login fail

Tags: lync, office365-apps, skype-for-business

I'm using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com to run a test connection to the Skype for Business (Lync) server but I keep getting a failed test connection.

Couldn't sign in. Error: Error Message: No common authentication method detected..
Error Type: AuthenticationException.
Error Code: 0.
Realm: SIP Communications Service.
Response Code: 401.
Response Text: Unauthorized.

The suggestions on how to resolve have so far not helped, any ideas what I could try or has anyone successfully resolved an issue like this before?

Comment: This is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 3):

Issue was resolved after entering the following DNS entries. 2 CNAME and 2 SRV entries were added.

Added 2 CNAME records, which were for "sip" and "lyncdiscover".

```
sip, CNAME, sipdir.online.lync.com.

lyncdiscover, CNAME, webdir.online.lync.com.
```

Added 2 SRV records, which were for "_sip._tls" and "_sipfederationtls._tcp".

```
_sip._tls, 100, 1, 443, sipdir.online.lync.com.

_sipfederationtls._tcp, 100, 1, 5061, sipfed.online.lync.com.
```

After doing this I was able to log into Skype for Business successfully.

---

The other option, which will only work per client is to enter the server and ports in manually in Skype for Business.

1. Go to Tools-Options.
2. Go to Advanced Connection Settings.
3. In here check "Manual Configuration".
4. For Internal server name enter "sipdir.online.lync.com:443".
5. For External server name enter "sipdir.online.lync.com:443".
6. Click on OK and proceed to log in.